# USB reset in WebUSB on MacOS not working?

Tags: macos, firmware, webusb

I'm working in Chrome for MacOS (108.0.5359.124) and Microsoft Edge (107.0.1418.62) on MacOS 12.6.1 (though confirmed the same issue on 13.0.1 as well), and the `reset()` method of WebUSB does not seem to work - I get no error on the console, but the device also doesn't see the reset.

Meanwhile, the same code *does* generate a USB reset in Chrome on Linux (same version, 108.0.5359.124, under Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 5.4.0).

The code is here:

```js
const connectButton = document.getElementById("connect");
const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");

let device;
connectButton.onclick = async () => {
  device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({
    filters: []
  });
  await device.open();
  console.log("open:", device);
  await device.selectConfiguration(1);
  console.log("select config 1:", device);
  await device.claimInterface(0);
  console.log("claim interface 0:", device);
};

resetButton.onclick = async () => {
    console.log("Device before reset: ", device);
    await device.reset();
    console.log("Device after reset:", device);
}
```

I see all the console logging, and no errors are thrown.  (If I try to claim one of the HID interfaces on this device, I do get errors - but I believe that's expected). I've also tried *without* the `device.selectConfiguration()` and `device.claimInterface()` calls - exactly the same behavior (ie, no errors, but it doesn't work).

Is there something under MacOS preventing it from sending the reset?  I can get similar code working on MacOS under `node.js` using WebUSB calls, but I suspect it's actually using `libusb` under the hood...  I should say that the device in question has firmware written in Zephyr 3.0 (I wrote a substantial part of it).  I haven't gotten resets to work with other devices either, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1189418, it seems like `USBDevice.reset()` does not work properly on macOS.

Even though a patch was submitted to fix this behaviour, it was reverted due to an expected libusb issue: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2936179

I've pinged the Chromium team at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1189418#c15. We may want to follow up there.

Comment: Thanks!  I will be looking at that area for followups.  I don't have a login, so I'll be view-only, but I greatly appreciate the bump.